# Export Slack Files

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am the workplace owner and migrating a workspace away from Slack. I cannot find any solution to export/download my workplace files (actual files, not URLs).

Any insights on how to get a folder with all public uploads?

Answer (score 1):

You should try `backupery` for slack. Worked really well when I had to do it.

Comment: Check this https://www.backupery.com/backupery-for-slack-312/

Comment: Yes, I follow that, and it leads to .exe file : /